# SVG Path.getPointAtLength returning wrong values

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm writing an application that uses SVG for displaying information and using a `<path>` to arrange a dynamic amount of positions on an ellipse. However points in the lower left corner were coming out past where they should be. So I wrote a quick script to check where the points are and made this (inserted via the Chrome JS console:

```
a = document.getElementById("svg-table-underlay");
len = a.getTotalLength();
for (i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
    line = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "line");
    line.setAttributeNS(null, "x1", a.getPointAtLength(i).x);
    line.setAttributeNS(null, "y1", a.getPointAtLength(i).y);
    line.setAttributeNS(null, "x2", a.getPointAtLength(i + 1).x);
    line.setAttributeNS(null, "y2", a.getPointAtLength(i + 1).y);
    line.setAttributeNS(null, "style", "stroke:#ff0000; stroke-width:3;");
    document.getElementById("svg-dragto").appendChild(line);
}
```

The path with ellipse is represented as this

```
<path d="M 212,250 A 300,140 0 1 0 212,249 Z" id="svg-table-underlay" fill="url(#wood)" />
```

I found my problem: the points in the lower left corner are calculated oddly causing the getPointAtLength() function to return points that are not correct. However the ellipse itself is drawn correctly. What could be the cause of this and are there anyways to get around it? (I'm using Chrome 21 and this only has to work in WebKit browsers)

[image: Path Tracing Oddness]

Comment: what do you need the lines for? to stroke (a part of?) the ellipse? if so you might be able to use `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` instead of creating lines.

Comment: I need the lines to go from one of the circles to another starting and ending at the edge of the ellipse. The placement also has to be dynamic (no static coords) because there can be a varying number of circles.

Comment: Something like http://jsfiddle.net/9KjED/?

Comment: YES! But, a strait line going from one point on the ellipse to another on the other side. (Think connecting 2 circles with a line)

Answer (score 1):

You can draw the ellipse with two arcs...

```
<path d="M 20, 200
        a 300,140 0 1,0 600,0
        a 300,140 0 1,0 -600,0
        z " id="svg-table-underlay" fill="#000" />
```

Where 300 is `rx`, 140 is `ry`, and 600 is `rx * 2`

http://jsfiddle.net/z6tTY/